# Avoid TypeScript "never" when iterating one of several strongly typed Maps

Tags: javascript, typescript, mapping, typed-arrays

So you have a couple strongly typed Maps and you're building a UI that makes use of them by iterating, but you could be iterating over one or the other depending on another variable. TypeScript complains about the type "never" in an odd situation. (in fact TypeScript seems to have poor support for maps in general).

Consider this simplified example:

```
let isFirstPicked = false;
const testMap = !isFirstPicked ? MMeasurementType : MMeasurementSize;
const items = [...testMap.keys()].map(
    key =>  key: ${key}, name: ${testMap.get(key).displayName}`
);
console.log(names);
```

This works just fine, but TypeScript complains about

```
testMap.get(key)
```

> Argument of type '"T_SHIRT" | "DRESS" | "JACKET" | "PANTS" | "SHOES" | "XS" | "S" | "M" | "L" | "XL" | "XXL"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
>     Type '"T_SHIRT"' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2345)

I do not like using "any" but this makes the error go away:

```
(testMap as any).get(key)
```

Here are my typings:

```
export interface IDisplayName {
    displayName: string;
}

export type TMeasurementType =
    | "T_SHIRT"
    | "DRESS"
    | "JACKET"
    | "PANTS"
    | "SHOES";
export const MMeasurementType = new Map<TMeasurementType, IDisplayName>([
    ["T_SHIRT", { displayName: "T-Shirts" }],
    ["DRESS", { displayName: "Dresses" }],
    ["JACKET", { displayName: "Jackets" }],
    ["PANTS", { displayName: "Pants" }],
    ["SHOES", { displayName: "Shoes" }],
]);

export type TMeasurementSize = "XS" | "S" | "M" | "L" | "XL" | "XXL";
export const MMeasurementSize = new Map<TMeasurementSize, IDisplayName>([
    ["XS", { displayName: "XS" }],
    ["S", { displayName: "Small" }],
    ["M", { displayName: "Medium" }],
    ["L", { displayName: "Large" }],
    ["XL", { displayName: "XL" }],
    ["XXL", { displayName: "Double XL" }],
]);
```

Comment: Why not `const names = [...testMap.values()].map(display => display.displayName);`?

Comment: Yep that's it! I am actually using the key in my code too, but just after posting this I realized the answer.

Answer (score 5):

To answer the "why" question, consider the following

```
interface Phone {
    turnOn()
    turnOff()
    ring()
}

interface Printer {
    turnOn()
    turnOff()
    print()
}
```

Let's add a new type, which is either a Phone or a Printer:

```
type Device = Phone | Printer
```

Mathematically, it's a Union of the set of phones and the set of printers. That's why it's called "union type". Now, given a Device object, what do we know for sure? Can it be turned on or off? Sure, because both the Phone and the Printer can do that. But can it print? The answer is generally no, because it might just happen to be a Phone, which can't. Can it ring? Similarly, the answer is no, because it can be a Printer. That is, the Device type only has methods that are common to Phone and Printer. That gives us the

**fun fact #1**: a *union* of compound types contains an *intersection* of their parts.

Now consider:

```
type FaxMachine = Phone & Printer
```

This is an "intersection type" and represents an object which is a Phone and a Printer at the same time. Can it be turned on/off? Sure. Can it `ring`? The answer is yes, because it *is* a Phone. Can it `print`? Again, yes, because it *is* a Printer. So,

**fun fact #2**: an *intersection* of compound types contains a *union* of their parts.

Back to the Maps example,

```
type keyA = 'x' | 'y' | 'a'
type keyB = 'x' | 'y' | 'b'

type A = Map<keyA, any>
type B = Map<keyB, any>

type U = A | B
```

What is the type of the keys of `U`? According to the above, it's `keyA & keyB`, that is, `'x' | 'y'`. If the maps have disjoint sets of keys, as in

```
type keyA = 'a1' | 'a2'
type keyB = 'b1' | 'b2'
```

then the type of the keys of `U` will be an empty set, or `never`.

In your code, the type of

```
!isFirstPicked ? MMeasurementType : MMeasurementSize
```

is inferred as

```
Map<TMeasurementSize, IDisplayName> | Map<TMeasurementType, IDisplayName>
```

respectively, the keys  have type

```
TMeasurementSize & TMeasurementType
```

which is `never` since there's no intersection.

Docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types

Comment: That's pretty helpful, though I don't understand the inner workings of TS enough to get the (Union) and (intersection) references. So like if the yet types shared items ( a or b or c or d, and c or d or e or f) would never become c or d?  Link to docs?

Comment: @Methodician: added some explanations

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out I was just under-utilizing the power of Maps, treating them more like dictionaries. Here is better code that also avoids the error:

```
let isFirstPicked = false;
const testMap = !isFirstPicked ? MMeasurementType : MMeasurementSize;
const items = [...testMap.entries()].map(
    ([key, value]) => `key: ${key}, name: ${value.displayName}`
);
console.log(items);
```